# jquery change input outcome when select with select

Tags: jquery, html, events

currently when i choose #choice He > #He Boy > #outcome is "Boy", after that when i change #choice to She, the #outcome is still "Boy". can I know is there a way that when i switch the #choice the #outcome will be change to.

```
<select id="choice">
    <option value="He" selected="selected">He</option>
    <option value="She">She</option>
</select>
<p>
    <select id="He">
        <option value="choose" selected="selected" Disabled Selected value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="Boy">Boy</option>
        <option value="Man">Man</option>
    </select>

    <select id="She">
        <option value="choose" selected="selected" Disabled Selected value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="Girl">Girl</option>
    <option value="Woman">Woman</option>
    </select>
</p>
<input type="text" id="outcome" readonly>
```

**Jquery Script** :

```
$(function() {
    $('#He').show(); 
    $('#choice').change(function(){
        if($('#choice').val() == 'He') {
            $('#He').show().prop({disabled: false}); 
        } 
        else {
            $('#He').hide().prop({disabled: true}); 
        } 
    });

    $('#She').hide(); 
    $('#choice').change(function(){
        if($('#choice').val() == 'She') {
            $('#She').show().prop({disabled: false }); 
        } 
        else {
            $('#She').hide().prop({disabled: true }); 
        } 
    });
});

$( "#He" ).change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $( this ).each(function() {
         $(str += $( this ).val()).show();
    });
    $( "#outcome" ).val( str );
  })
  .trigger( "change" );

$( "#She" ).change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $( this ).each(function() {
         $(str += $( this ).val()).show();
    });
    $( "#outcome" ).val( str );
  })
  .trigger( "change" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
$(function () {
    $('#choice').change(function () {
        var he = $(this).val() == 'He';
        $('#He').toggle(he).prop({
            disabled: !he
        });
        $('#She').toggle(!he).prop({
            disabled: he
        });
        $('#' + (he ? 'He' : 'She')).change()
    }).change();

    $("#He, #She").change(function () {
        $("#outcome").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZLK42/)

Comment: Yes!! cool, thanks for your help. I'm new to jquery. beens playing it for days and still having trouble..